# Splunk subsearch for regex outputs

Tags: search, splunk, splunk-query

I want a single search query for below splunk query.

First search will give me a dynamic field myorderid

index=mylog "trigger.rule: Id - * : Unexpected System Error" | rex field=_raw "Id -""(?[^:]*)" | table  myorderid

I want to pass the above myorderid in below search criteria

index=mylog API=Order orderid=myorderid

Can anyone please help me to create a single query using subsearch in splunk.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the obvious?

```
index=mylog API=Order orderid=
[ search index=mylog "trigger.rule: Id - * : Unexpected System Error" 
    | rex "Id - (?<myorderid>[^:]*)" | fields myorderid ]
```